# How do I update objects using a DbContext?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How do I use the class `DbContext` to update a collection of objects?

I have a `DbContext` Class called "Animals". `Animals` has a `DbSet` called "Reptiles" which is another class. I can query the `Animals` with Linq to get the objects I want from the `Reptiles`. Now, how do I update those objects which I got from the query? I want to save back into the database the changes I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context should have a method that does this for you, I believe it's called `SaveChanges()`. With EF (like most ORMs) there isn't a way of saving a single entity (not easily at least).

Answer (score 2):

Call SaveChanges() on the DbContext

Answer (score 1):

**Entity Framework:** `SaveChanges();`
**Linq-to-SQL:**      `SubmitChanges();`